# why gdbserver is not deployed in android64?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

What is the exact purpose of `$(NDKBasePath)\prebuilt\android-arm\gdbserver\gdbserver` and why it is not deployed in android64 (it's deployed only in android)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDB is Android debugger.

Specifically, Delphi uses GDB for debugging 32bit Android applications. For debugging 64bit Android applications it uses different debugger LLDB.

That answers why it is not deployed in android64

You can find lldb files in ...\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\Android\lldb folder.

For more information you can read [Using Debuggers](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/gdb)

Comment: There are also some lldb files in NDK folder, but I am not sure what role they play in Delphi because I am sharing SDK and NDK with Android Studio.